# Recharts installation problem in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recharts

I can't install recharts in my react project, these errors appeared in the terminal. What should I do? to fix this issue and install recharts safely or you can suggest me a good chart that I can use in my react projects.

[image: problem showed in my terminal]

Comment: if your issue is with `rectjs` why are you tagging `vue.js`? - seems some library you have isn't compatible with the latest rectjs (version 18) - check the library (recharts), there may be a solution - [here's a recharts issue that will help](https://github.com/recharts/recharts/issues/2813)

Comment: they said use react dom version 17 instead of 18, I think avoid recharts for react project

Comment: it's your call - I didn't read that issue, just found it for you using google

Comment: Looks like `recharts` has a peer dependency on React 16 and 17. It's currently not installable with React 18. Either revert back to React 17 or fork the `recharts` repos, fix the peer dependency and any issues that arise from that, and open a PR to merge in your update/fix for others.

Comment: Looks like a fix is already in the works: https://github.com/recharts/recharts/pull/2820

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
npm config set legacy-peer-deps true
npm i recharts
```